# Twisted TypeError in sendLine

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted, rtsp

I am using [python-RTSP](https://github.com/odie5533/Python-RTSP) to run RTSP using Twisted and Python3. I am trying access RTSP information for the youtube link using above configuration. Ihave to use Python3 as my remaining code is in Python3.

I am sending command using

```
self.sendLine('%s %s RTSP/1.0' % (command, path))
```

where Command is *DESCRIBE* and Path is the url

```
rtsp://r7---sn-a5m7zu7d.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlFHOtrHD-E8RMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

I get Error with following statement:

```
File "/home/akshay_v/valuconnex-python/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 637, in sendLine
        return self.transport.write(str(line + self.delimiter))
    builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

self.delimiter = b'\r\n'
line is the *str* passed as argument in above statement.
```

How to get this working?

Comment: It is there in the library used. When I try to modify it to a string, error shows up that the 'Data cannot be unicode'

Comment: Why don't you use `RTSPClient.sendCommand()` instead of copy pasting the code that function uses

Comment: Actually RTSP.sendCommand() uses twisted/protocols/basic.py's sendLine(). The line in above error is the argument passed by sendCommand().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jean-Paul says, you can't use Python 3 to run python-RTSP.

If you're curious about the exact nature of this failure, the issue is that `transport.write` takes a `bytes` object.  On Python 2 that is the same type as `str`, on Python 3 it is its own type.  The type that is analagous to Python 3's `str` on Python 2 is `unicode`, and you can't write `unicode` to a socket, so you can't pass it to `transport.write`.

However, the line of code you're showing there in `twisted.protocols.basic` looks like an incorrectly-modified version of Twisted; I can't find a version of Twisted that has ever called `str` in that location.  How did you get this version of Twisted, and have you tried upgrading to the most recent release (14.0.0 as of this writing)?

Comment: Thanks, Updated Twisted (to 14.0.0). And Converting string to bytes before using `sendLine` command. Able to Move ahead. Thanks for the Detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear as though python-RTSP has been ported to Python 3 yet.  Try running it on Python 2.7 (or perhaps even Python 2.6, as its README suggests) instead.  Python 3 is incompatible with Python 2 and software that has not been ported to it will not work.